# Facebook does not recognize OG tags of website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I added metadata for og:title, og:image etc.
But facebook for some reason does not see them.
I get error: 
Object at URL 'http://www.heliconbooks.com/article/authorlanding' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

I looked at the facebook scraper and for some reason these meta tags are omitted. When I look at the source, I see them.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.heliconbooks.com%2Farticle%2Fauthorlanding

There you can see that FB doesn't see any OG tags. If I look at the source of the website you linked, there are no OG tags as well. So, fix you code according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content#tags

Comment: I know this link and I checked it.
When I click view source I did see it.
Try the following link: http://www.heliconbooks.com/?id=authorlanding&lang=he
Facebook claims the same error while I do see the facebook og:title

Comment: Yes, and? You don't even have OG tags in your source code, how should this even work then? Have you even read the FB docs?

Comment: You should edit your question then if the link has changed! In this new URL, there are only tags for `og:url`  and `og:image` , which is not enough! I mean the error message from the debugger says it all: `Object at URL 'http://www.heliconbooks.com/article/authorlanding' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.`

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the reason, facebook has seen a different page template since my system has adaptive templates based on visitor IP.
Now it shows an image, but not the image I wanted. I guess I have to continue researching it.